# How to run 2 loops at the same time using asyncio

Tags: python, loops, python-asyncio

I'm pretty new to asyncio, so lot of things are still way too far from my understanding yet, anyway.

I got a main while loop that basically just draws some stuff on the screen using PyGame, and what i'd like to do, is to run another while loop asynchronously, that keeps updating some data to be rendered.

```
async def update(reader, writer):
    while True:
        json_data = await reader.read(1000)
        self.json_data = json.loads(json_data)

def run(self):
    while True:
        self.draw()
```

Comment: Simply create [two different tasks](https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hello_world.html#creating-tasks). `self.draw()` should be asynchronous though. Use [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/threads.html) if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try threading:

```
import threading

async def update(reader, writer):
    while True:
        json_data = await,reader.read(1000)
        self.json_data = json.loads(json_data)

def run(self):
    while True:
        self.draw()

t = threading.Thread(target=update,args=(reader,writer))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=run,args=(self))
t.start()
t2.start()
```

Threading will run both processes at once!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I thought asyncio would do the job in any way...I didn't want to use threads from the beginning.